# Service account as an Azure DevOps organisation owner

Tags: azure-devops

I am looking into using a service account as an Azure DevOps Organisation owner. We are going to create multiple Organisations and a service account seems like a logical solution to reduce named account limitations.
Could I please get advise on this approach or a better way of doing organisation owners, rather than named accounts?
My path is -

1. Service Accounts as Org owners.
2. Add Service Account to Entra's DevOps Admin group along with Global Admins.
3. Create a project template for Dev-teams and add the Service Account to project collections admins
4. ICT to do the monitoring & governance and restrict Organisation creation by other teams. Business units manage their Projects and Teams.

We are starting greenfield and the named account solution seems restricting given Staff do not have much understanding on DevOps and Azure.
I am seeking to understand the cons of this approach and any future problems for the development teams?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to have multiple organizations? It's going to massively complicate billing and cross-team information sharing.

Comment: What accounts do you mean by **Service Account**s? If it is service principals, it is mentioned in [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#about-service-principals-and-managed-identities) that _Service principals can't be organization owners or create organizations_.

Comment: Hi  @DanielMann , Yes I struggled with the thought for a few days given the security & autonomy requirements around our business units, which are very independent. But we decided to go with a single Organization only at the moment . We may have to diversify given our few branches are overseas too  , but we will wait for the business to raise their concerns . We may go with BackRightUp backup solution which allows for easy project restores to a new Org.

Comment: Hi @MiaoTian-MSFT, It is not a service principle , but I was thinking of a service account  only as the Org owner. But I was advised that by definition service accounts are to do repetitive and non monitored jobs mostly. So, I had to create a new account, with MFA and add to PIM... which essentially what a team member would do.   I have dropped the idea , as it seems like a bad choice. Although, I am still keen to understand how can I do template for new-user  & project creations. Thanks again for your input.